# LDAP User Group Service : how configure?

Tags: geoserver

I try to list the users inside my group from my LDAP server. I followed the documentation and example here : https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/security/usergrouprole/usergroupservices.html

So, I have this file :

```
  <org.geoserver.security.ldap.LDAPUserGroupServiceConfig>
  <id>-7aace7bb:189404b68f5:-7ffe</id>
  <name>ad-users</name>
  <className>org.geoserver.security.ldap.LDAPUserGroupService</className>
  <serverURL>ldap://ip:389/dc=main,dc=local</serverURL>
  <groupSearchBase>OU=database</groupSearchBase>
  <groupFilter>cn={0}</groupFilter>
  <groupNameAttribute>cn</groupNameAttribute>
  <allGroupsSearchFilter>cn=*</allGroupsSearchFilter>
  <groupSearchFilter>member={0}</groupSearchFilter>
  <groupMembershipAttribute>member</groupMembershipAttribute>
  <userSearchBase>dc=main,dc=local</userSearchBase>
  <userFilter>sAMAccountName</userFilter>
  <userNameAttribute>sAMAccountName={0}</userNameAttribute>
  <allUsersSearchFilter>sAMAccountName=*</allUsersSearchFilter>
  <useTLS>false</useTLS>
  <useNestedParentGroups>false</useNestedParentGroups>
  <maxGroupSearchLevel>10</maxGroupSearchLevel>
  <nestedGroupSearchFilter>(member={0})</nestedGroupSearchFilter>
  <bindBeforeGroupSearch>true</bindBeforeGroupSearch>
  <rolePrefix>ROLE_</rolePrefix>
  <convertToUpperCase>true</convertToUpperCase>
  <user>bind</user>
  <password>password</password>
  <passwordEncoderName>strongPbePasswordEncoder</passwordEncoderName>
  <passwordPolicyName>default</passwordPolicyName>
</org.geoserver.security.ldap.LDAPUserGroupServiceConfig>
```

With this configuration, I have the groups inside OU=database, but not users inside them.

When I do a ldapsearch request, I have this result :

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=database,dc=main,dc=local> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: member
#

# database, main.local
dn: OU=database,DC=main,DC=local

# SVC_SIG, database, main.local
dn: CN=SVC_SIG,OU=database,DC=main,DC=local

# GGSU_APPLI_SIG_ADMIN, database, main.local
dn: CN=GGSU_APPLI_SIG_ADMIN,OU=database,DC=main,DC=local
member: CN=Jean Pierre,OU=Project,OU=App,OU=DSI,DC=main,
 DC=local

# GGSU_APPLI_SIG_R, database, main.local
dn: CN=GGSU_APPLI_SIG_R,OU=database,DC=main,DC=local
member: CN=test gis,OU=SIG,OU=Home,DC=main,DC=local
```

So, I would like to list the sAMAccountName of Jean Pierre and test gis, but I got nothing with my configuration adapted from the documentation.

I have already configured the authentication provider and it works, I can connect with my sAMAccountName to my GeoServer :

[image: ldap authentication]

Comment: I don't know if it will help but I don't add the base to the URL but specify it in the `groupSearchBase` and `userSearchBase` - I also have `<userNameAttribute>uid</userNameAttribute>` and `<allUsersSearchFilter>(uid=*)</allUsersSearchFilter>`

Comment: Thanks, but change the base do nothing and the uid too (we don't use it, we use the sAMAccountName). With the base change, i still got my groups, but not my users. You have them inside your geoserver ?

Comment: I meant that your `<userNameAttribute>` had a filter in it and I don't and the oposite for `<allUserSearchFilter>`

Comment: Nice, so :
- the base must not be written in the url if we are looking for something from the base. It is possible to write it if we have an OU with users (as in the documentation)
- set `<userNameAttribute>` and `<allUserSearchFilter>` as you work (this just takes a long time for me, because I search from the base with many users)

So I have all users now, but I'm looking for how the membership relationship works now, because I just want to get my two users. Writing the same values ​​as in the documentation does not work. Can you share yours if you have it configured ? Thanks for help